# SSL certification error while connecting smartsheet to Jupyter via API access token

Tags: python, jupyter, smartsheet-api

I am using Jupyter to get data from smartsheet via API access token generated within Smartsheet.

```
import smartsheet #(pip install smartsheet-python-sdk package)

access_token = 'm2ihridpq4xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

ss_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)

ss_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)

sheet_ID = 313119xxxxxxxxxx

MySheet = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_ID)
```

```
**Error: SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)
During handling of the above exception, another exception
occurred:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.smartsheet.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2.0/sheets/3131191986546564 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)')))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
(SSLError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.smartsheet.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2.0/sheets/3131191986546564 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)')))")), 'SSL handshake error, old CA bundle or old OpenSSL?')**
```

I am getting this error on MAC laptop, provided by company only. I used same code and ran in it windows provided by company and its working fine.

I tried tried with python 2.7 and 3.7 but still can't figure out.

I have tried upgraded and degraded certifi, requests and OpenSSl module but still getting same error. 
Could anyone help me out????

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) would greatly improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make sure your version of the [Smartsheet Python SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk) is up to date with the latest version. Older versions of the SDK use TLS 1.0 and the Smartsheet API requires TLS 1.1 and higher to be used. Using an older version of the Python SDK will lead to certificate errors.
Secondly, I would investigate what version of OpenSSL is in your path and make sure the right and newer version is being used when you run your code.